# ASP.NET MVC3 dropdownlist not get selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I have this in my edit controller:

```
playerView.Users = new SelectList(repo.GetUsers(), "UserID", "UserName", player.User.UserID.ToString());
```

and this is how looks my dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUserID, Model.Users)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedUserID)
```

But I can´t get that selected user to my view (I always get first item in dropdownlist). In player.User is User with id, name, ... I tried UserID with or without ToString, UserName or just User but nothing helps. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
...
playerView.Users = new SelectList(repo.GetUsers(), "UserID", "UserName");
playerView.SelectedUserID = player.User.UserID.ToString();
return View(playerView);
```